# Intersection of Two Homeomorphic Copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

There is an exercise in Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" in the Van Kampen section that supposes that $\mathbb{R}P^2=U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n$ where each $U_i$ is open and homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The problem is to show that, for some $1\leq i\leq n$, we must have $(U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_{i-1})\cap U_i$ is either disconnected or empty.  My assumption is that I need to use Van Kampen's Theorem.

My issue is the case where $n=2$.  Then, for contradiction, I assume that $U_1\cap U_2$ is connected and non-empty.  But, I can't apply Van Kampen because I only have that it is connected, not path connected.

Is there some fact that says if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $X\cap Y$ is connected if and only if it is path connected?  Or, is there some way of doing this problem with only connectedness?  I can do the problem using homology.

Comment: Connected+open=path-connected

Comment: @Gina: That works in this case because $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is sufficiently nice, but not in general: Any connected but not path-connected space is an open, connected subspace of itself that is not path-connected. So there's a little bit for the OP to prove, still.

Comment: @squirrel: no, all I need to use is the fact that they are locally path-connected, which follow from the fact that each of the $U_{i}$ is homeomorphic to some Euclidean space. Nothing about $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$.

Comment: @Gina: You have used something nice about $\mathbb{R}P^2$, namely that it can be covered by open sets that are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The local path-connectedness is the "niceness" I had in mind. In this case, local path-connectedness is immediate from the description of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as a locally Euclidean space $U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_n$ with $U_i \cong \mathbb{R}^2$.